# Is packaged apps preferable over C++ for creating a cross-platform serial read/write application to communicate with my mbed electronics project?

Tags: c++, google-chrome, package

I would like to create a cross-platform serial read/write application to communicate with my mbed electronics project.  I cannot decide whether to code this application in Chrome packed app or c++(using the openFrameworks framework).  I have more experience coding in html and javascript than I do in c++, but I wouldn't mind learning c++.  What drew me to the packed app idea was the ability to write code in html and javascript.  Eventually my project will be open-sourced.  What are some of the pros and cons of using packaged apps versus c++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ can be used to do chip level programming and to manipulate the chips that require lot of coding in order to implement the functionality of your desire.

Packaged apps deliver an experience as capable as a native app, but as safe as a web page. Just like web apps, packaged apps are written in HTML5, JavaScript, and CSS. But packaged apps look and behave like native apps, and they have native-like capabilities that are much more powerful than those available to web apps.

Packaged apps would be a modern concept and it would be a better option because it gives more importance to your project when the reviewers of your project find that you are using a new concept.

Answer (score 1):

I'm working-on in one app that I need for setting-up embedded devices, the app must be cross plattform because it will be used in Windows, OSX and Linux.
I'm developing it in java using RXTX library that is tested and work fine in the three plattforms.